# How to do Typescript JSDoc for the fields of a typed object function parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

Below is a Typescript function signature x and it accepts ABC as optional parameter. If pass in ABC, a and b are the required fields.

```
async x (options: ABC = {}): Promise<string> 

interface ABC {
  a: string
  b: number
}
```

Should the JSDOC look like this

```
 /** 
   * @param {ABC} [options]
   * @param {string} options.a
   * @param {number} options.b
   * @return {Promise<string>} 
   */
```

Or this

```
 /** 
   * @param {ABC} [options]
   * @param {string} [options.a]
   * @param {number} [options.b]
   * @return {Promise<string>} 
   */
```

Comment: Do you need JSDoc **and** Typescript? Surely `type SomeFunc = (options?: Options) => Promise<whatever>` would suffice?

Comment: It is required for business purpose

Comment: Can you fix your code so that it is valid Typescript. Sure I can guess, but you shouldn't make us do that. For example, you are missing the function keyword. And the default argument has the wrong type. Should `a` and `b` be optional members of `ABC`, or should `x`'s arg have a different type?

Answer (score 1):

Document the structure of `ABC` in the JSDoc for `ABC` not in the JSDoc for `x`:

```js
interface ABC {
    /**
     * describe `a` here
     */
    a: string

    /**
     * describe `b` here
     */
    b: number
}

/**
 * @param {ABC} options
 * @return {Promise<string>}
 */
async function x (options: ABC): Promise<string> {
    // IOU a promise
}
```

If there is nothing to describe about `ABC.a` or `ABC.b`, the you can skip that JSDoc altogether. Typescript and your Typescript IDE already know that `a` is a string and `b` is a number from the interface definition. Your proposed JSDoc would be redundant even if it were correct (it is not).

*The signature for `x` in the question produces an error, so I had to guess you intent. See my comment under the question.*

Answer (score 0):

To clarify and maybe soften the point that Inigo is making,
it is unnecessary to provide type definitions in your JSDoc
when using TypeScript. If you create an interface for your `options`
parameter and document it with JSDoc, your Typescript IDE
will provide both autocompletion and documentation for the parameter.

More importantly, however, let's not forget that the purpose of
documentation is to help developers use your code--not just to provide
type definitions. As an example, I've written a working
(if not completely dumb) function and added some documentation:

```js
/**
 * Provides options for {@link dumbSubstring}.
 */
declare interface DumbSubstringOptions {
  /** The `start` index for {@link dumbSubstring}. */
  start?: number;
  /** The `end` index for {@link dumbSubstring}. */
  end?: number;
  /**
   * If {@link dumbSubstring} should reject if the value of {@link end}
   * is greater than the string length.
   */
  rejectOnInvalidLength?: boolean;
  /** If {@link dumbSubstring} should reject if `val` is an empty string. */
  rejectOnEmptyString?: boolean;
}

/**
 * Substrings a value.
 * @param val A string to `substring()`
 * @param options (optional) Provides additional options.
 * @return A promise of the `substring` operation.
 */
async function dumbSubstring(
  val: string,
  options?: DumbSubstringOptions
): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (options?.rejectOnEmptyString && val.length === 0) {
      reject(new Error("val is an empty string."));
    }

    if (options?.rejectOnInvalidLength && (options.end ?? 0) > val.length) {
      reject(new Error("end parameter is greater than the length of val."));
    }

    if (options?.rejectOnInvalidLength && (options.start ?? 0) > val.length) {
      reject(new Error("start parameter is greater than the length of val."));
    }

    resolve(val.substring(options?.start ?? 0, options?.end));
  });
}
```

VSCode displays the available options when I call the function:

[image: VSCode auto-complete interface]

And when I hover over an option, VSCode displays its JSDoc:

[image: VSCode JSDoc interface]